# How to display two mismatching dictionaries in a bar graph using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a graph which will display data from dictionaries. My problem is that sometimes number of values in dictionaries (`ME_Requests` and `non_ME_Requests`) are mismatching and this generates the following error:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Could someone help me flatten values so if there is a mismatch then only one bar will show instead of two? Thanks in advance!

my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#sample data
ME_Requests = {'John Doe': 47, 'Amanda Doe': 27, 'Maria Doe': 26}
non_ME_Requests = {'John Doe': 105, 'Amanda Doe': 64, 'Maria Doe': 48, 'Dimitri Doe': 58}
month="Apr-2020"
X = np.arange(len(ME_Requests))
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.bar(X, ME_Requests.values(), width=0.2, align='center')
ax.bar(X-0.2, non_ME_Requests.values(), width=0.2, align='center')
ax.legend(('ME_Requests','non_ME_Requests'))
plt.xticks(X, ME_Requests.keys())
plt.title("Emails Closed per team member in {}".format(month) , fontsize=17)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I calculated length of `ME_Requests` and `non_ME_Requests` dictionaries separately. Plotted using length of bigger dictionary.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#sample data
ME_Requests = {'John Doe': 47, 'Amanda Doe': 27, 'Maria Doe': 26}
non_ME_Requests = {'John Doe': 105, 'Amanda Doe': 64, 'Maria Doe': 48, 'Dimitri Doe': 58}
month="Apr-2020"
X = np.arange(len(ME_Requests))
X_non_ME = np.arange(len(non_ME_Requests))
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.bar(X, ME_Requests.values(), width=0.2, align='center')
ax.bar(X_non_ME-0.2, non_ME_Requests.values(), width=0.2, align='center')
ax.legend(('ME_Requests','non_ME_Requests'))

# plt.xticks(X, ME_Requests.keys())
plt.xticks(X_non_ME, non_ME_Requests.keys())
plt.title("Emails Closed per team member in {}".format(month), fontsize=17)
plt.show()
```

Comment: doing something like this only works when the names in `ME_Requests` appear as a prefix of `non_ME_Requests`.  getting the data into a consistent data structure (e.g. a single Pandas dataframe) would be much more reliable if you had to work with any other data

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using `pandas`, I would create a dataframe that ensures consistent number of elements:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(ME_Requests.values(), index=ME_Requests.keys(), columns=['ME_Requests'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(non_ME_Requests.values(), index=non_ME_Requests.keys(), columns=['non_ME_Requests'])
df = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)

df.plot.bar()
```

[image]